# fcbkcomplete with ajax request to fetch data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i just tried fcbkcomplete in my project but i'm having a trouble calling an ajax request to fetch the result into the autocomplete do anyone know how to accomplish it ?

server side :

```
  public static string tagFriendAutocomplete()
{
    string Result = "";
    string query = "select fr.FRIEND_ID,c.[USER_NAME] from clients c inner join friends fr on c.CLIENT_ID=fr.FRIEND_ID and fr.CLIENT_ID=1 and c.[USER_NAME] like '%a%' ";

    DataTable dt = new SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.WebSiteConnectionString).getQueryResult(query);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Result += dt.Rows[i]["USER_NAME"] + ",";
        }
    }

    return Result;
}
```

client side :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#select3").fcbkcomplete({
                //"autoCompleteFriendTag/data.txt",
                addontab: true,
                maxitems: 10,
                input_min_size: 0,
                height: 10,
                cache: true,
                newel: false,
                select_all_text: "select"
            });

 });
```

i don't know where to put the jquery ajax code any help please i've been 2 days searching for a solution but sadly i cldn't find one my ajax code is :

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Testautocomplete.aspx/tagFriendAutocomplete',
                data: "{}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                  return  data.d.split(',');

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: see this http://blog.kaning.co.uk/archives/186

Comment: i didn't find any solution for my problem in the url you provide

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#select3").fcbkcomplete({
            json_url: 'Testautocomplete.aspx/tagFriendAutocomplete',
            addontab: true,
            maxitems: 10,
            input_min_size: 0,
            height: 10,
            cache: true,
            newel: false,
            select_all_text: "select"
        });
});
```

There is an important point, you have to send your data as `json` format by serializing it.

Your code behind should look like this;

```
public static string tagFriendAutocomplete()
{

   Dictionary<> jsonResult= new Dictionary<>();  
   string query = "select fr.FRIEND_ID,c.[USER_NAME] from clients c inner join friends fr           on c.CLIENT_ID=fr.FRIEND_ID and fr.CLIENT_ID=1 and c.[USER_NAME] like '%a%' ";

   DataTable dt = new  SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.WebSiteConnectionString).getQueryResult(query);
   if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
     for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
        jsonResult.Add(dt.Rows[i]["USER_NAME"], i); 
      }
   }

   var result = from r in jsonResult select new  
    {  
       key = r.Key,  
       value = r.Value  
    };  

   JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   context.Response.Write(ser.Serialize(result));
}
```

Comment: it didn't work i can't access my server side function : json_url: 'Testautocomplete.aspx/tagFriendAutocomplete',

Comment: Use generic handler. this is best method I have used so far